# I have a permission problem trying to create a user as admin in AWS Cognito with node js have a problem

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the AdminCreateUser method in the aws-sdk for nodejs, the credentials I am using belong to my user who has root access, but it is returning this error:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:user/xxxxxxxxxxx is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:userpool/us-east-2_xxxxxxxx with an explicit deny
```

what kind of additional permission I need or there something that I missed

I have the credentials on a .env file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_REGION=us-east-2

AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_COGNITO_SECRET_HASH=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=us-east-2_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see the IAM policies that are attached to this user, but the key is likely in this part of the error message:

```
...with an explicit deny
```

This means that part of your IAM policy on the user is explicitly denying this permission. Since `deny` will always override `allow`, even if you allow the correct permission, it will still fail.

Check your IAM policy for something that says:

```
"Effect": "Deny"
```